# How to reset variables with methods?

Tags: javascript

currently I encountered trouble with methods not working as expected with each other.
Here is an my problem:
[codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gZPPyz?editors=1011)
I have two methods initialize (resets numbers), rollDice (Increase roundscore number). I want for my roundscore to actually keep increasing. Instead of resetting due to initialize method. Normally without classes I would write like this: [codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jXWMwv?editors=1011).

Thanks in advance

HTML

```
<button class = "button--roll">Button Roll</button>
<script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Script.js

```
const elements = {
  buttonRoll: document.querySelector(".button--roll"),
};


class ButtonRoll {
  constructor(){
//     Properties
    this.buttonRoll = elements.buttonRoll;

//     Methods
    this.initialize;
    this.rollDice;
  }

  events(){
    let scores, roundScore;
    this.initialize(scores, roundScore);
    // this.buttonRoll.addEventListener('click', () => this.rollDice(scores, roundScore));


  }
  initialize(scores, roundScore){
    scores = 0;
    roundScore = 0;

    this.buttonRoll.addEventListener('click', () => this.rollDice(scores, roundScore));
  }
  rollDice(scores, roundScore){

    let dice1 = 4;

    roundScore += dice1;
    console.log(roundScore);
  }
}

let buttonRoll = new ButtonRoll;

buttonRoll.events();
```

Comment: `scores` and `roundScore` should be member variables, not function parameters (which are not "stored" between calls)

Comment: Instead of setting closure variable inside `initialize` method variable `scores` and `roundScore` should be defined as class prop. So you can define method eg. reset and set this.scores to 0.

Comment: Thanks for insanely fast response I solved the issue. [Codepen finished](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gZPgRp?editors=1011).